# Get distinct values from a column of DataTable in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-2.0, datarowcollection

I am working on a legacy project which was developed using .NET Framework 2.0.
In this project, I get distinct values from `DataRowCollection` by `ItemNo` column. I am only interested in `ItemNo`. The `DataRow` consist of `ItemNo`, `Qty` and `Date`.

I am thinking of iterating the `DataRowCollection` and adding the unique `ItemNo` into a list of string as below (not tested)

```
var items =  new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow orderItem in rows)
{
     var itemNo = orderItem["ITEMNO"].ToString().Trim();
     if(items.Find(delegate(string str) { return str == itemNo ;}) == null)
     {
            items.Add(itemNo);
     }
 }
```

Is there a better way of doing this without LINQ (.Net Framework 2.0 doesnt like LINQ)

Comment: you use `Contains` method to find `specific item` from `List`. `if(!items.Contains(itemNo))
     {
            items.Add(itemNo);
     }`

Comment: how about don't run n^2 on your collection and use a dictionary for your items

Comment: Do you mean you need Distinct values from `ITEMNO` column?

Comment: @RezaAghaei , yes unique values for ITEMNO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Given a data table:
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ITEMNO");
dt.Rows.Add("1 ");
dt.Rows.Add(" 1");
dt.Rows.Add("2");

var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var itemNo = dr["ITEMNO"].ToString().Trim();

    // Take advantage of O(1) lookup:
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(itemNo))
    {
        dict.Add(itemNo, true);
    }
}

// Get list from dictionary keys:
var items = new List<string>(dict.Keys);
```

If you can install .Net 3.5 on the server, and reference System.Core.dll in your application, you can leverage HashSets which would modify the above code to:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var itemNo = dr["ITEMNO"].ToString().Trim();    

    // Only unique elements are added to the hash set, 
    // no need to check for duplicates
    hashSet.Add(itemNo);    
}

var items = new List<string>(hashSet);
```

The benefit of using HashSet over a Dictionary is admittedly trivial, but I'd prefer it since I don't care for the arbitrary bool value in the dictionary, but you'd need to meet the .Net 3.5 and reference requisites.

Answer (score 1):

To get distinct values form a column you can use this method:

```
List<T> SelectDistict<T>(DataTable table, string column)
{
    DataTable temp = new DataView(table).ToTable(true, column);
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    foreach (DataRow row in temp.Rows)
        items.Add(row.Field<T>(column));
    return items;
}
```

In above method I used [`DataView.ToTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx) which by passing `true` as first argument, selects distinct values.

Here is the usage example:

```
List<string> items = SelectDistict<string>(yourDataTable, "ITEMNO");
```

**Note**

If you need to trim values, you can change above code and first create a clone copy of the `DataTable`. Then add a computed column which contains, trimmed value from the given column name for distinct values by assigning `TRIM(column)` to `Expression` property of column. Then follow the steps using the new trimmed column like above code.