# Select unique values within a DataColumn from a DataTable?

Tags: c#, select, datatable, unique, datacolumn

In SQL to get the **DISTINCT** values in a column I would do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM TableName;
```

I would like to do something like this but for a DataTable's DataColumn. I am aware of this way (follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627261/get-distinct-values-from-a-column-of-datatable-in-net-2-0)) which does the usual intuitive way of using the fact that we can check if what we have Contains(whatWeWant) or not, and if it doesn't we can add it to some container of unique items. What I would like to know is if there is something like the following out there:

```
var uniqueObjects = dataTable.Columns[0].Distinct().ToList();
```

I am also aware from reading the [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) that the DataColumn class does not have a method called Distinct but if there is something like this that you guys are aware of please let me know. If not I will resort to making a Distinct extension method with the intuitive way of using Contains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project's references:

```
using System.Data;

var uniqueObjects = dataTable
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row => row[0])
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Very clean answer I like it, Ill try it out

Comment: By the way I would change the variable row to column since it goes through columns not rows

Comment: It will, in fact, enumerate through an  [System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).  I would also recommend using the [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension as @m-kudi did below if you know the column's type ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like...

```
      var uniqueObjects =  dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>x.Field<ColumnType>("ColumnName")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Let me try it out, looks promising